# Using highcharts for Rails (via LazyHighCharts), is there a tooltip for yDateFormat for having datetime data on the Yaxis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I have an issue where I have nested array data set consisting of [x,y] coordinates for a spline or scatter chart in rails LazyHighCharts, and the y coordinate is the date, in milliseconds, such as 1776600000000.

Is there such a thing as `yDateFormat` for `tooltip` ?

It seems logical there would be, since there is a:

```
tooltip: {
   xDateFormat: '%Y-%m'
}
```

The whole idea is that when I mouse over a data point on a spline or scatter chart(I'm trying either option), the date will popup.  But right now the date is popping up in a huge ms number, 1776600000000. I am not getting a fix to day.

Additionally, perhaps it would be nice to also include a `pointFormat` for something like:

```
tooltip: {
   pointFromat: "Yada yada {point.y} and yadayda {point.x}"
   xDateFormat: '%Y-%m'
}
```

Also for my y-axis settings, I have:

```
`chart.yAxis(title: { text: 'Yadayada'}, type: 'datetime' )
```

Any help appreciated.  Pretty new to highcharts, and relatively newer to Rails

Answer (score 0):

From Highcharts site you can use the formatter callback to return wanted date format.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4pf1xw02/

```
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
        Highcharts.dateFormat('%e - %b - %Y',
          new Date(this.y)) +
        ' date';
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: Thank you!  However, We are doing all the options of the graph inside a .rb model file in Rails, so I don't know that that JS is allowed inside a .rb file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the Ruby. I thought that you will be able to reproduce JS code to Ruby and this guideline could be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you. I actually found that in Ruby files you can have a section of JS code in double quotes `" "`, and then call `.js_code` right after the last quote and have that code work, despite it being in a `.rb` file.   For example, in the code you shared, having `"function() {... }".js_code`. What an issue was, was trying to properly extract the data of my nested array out with `this.options.y` or such, and going into dev tools while running `debugger;` in the JS code with someone helped, as we played around with console looking to get at the data we were seeking from the Rails query.  Thanks!